# Is it possible to use Ubuntu sources in Debian and vice versa?

Tags: apt, 20.04

Is it possible to use Ubuntu apt sources on Debian 10? Also is it possible to use Debian apt sources on Ubuntu? After saying that, is this recommended?

Comment: Yes if you do your evaluation of consequences and consider how you'll use your machine into the future (ie. come *release-upgrade* time into the future and take allowance for the pitfalls that could hit you then). I do it both ways, and don't have a problem, but I restrict it to specific packages, and because of the time difference between them, the research required is a chore.. but for the few package where I'm wanting to do it, I think it's worth it  (if you don't understand what I'm alluding to, I'd recommend avoiding it)

Comment: ps: thanks... I have a *buster* box that failed to upgrade to *bullseye*... it could be such a Ubuntu package (*not available in Debian*) that causes the conflict, I'll check... thanks for the clue.  ie. at first it may work... but minefields are often left for the future, and you need to remember & deal with them....  add too many packages & the only fix maybe re-install (ie. problems are often not petty in the future).

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Search box at the top of every AskUbuntu page on this topic, you will discover that folks have tried this before, and it frequently ended badly.

Ubuntu and Debian compile (mostly) the same source code...but at different times and against against different dependency versions. The results are often incompatible outside the specific distro and release. A .deb package is NOT universal.

Some packages (like scripts instead of compiled software) can indeed cross over without problems. However, such crossovers are untested and not guaranteed to work.